# bootstrap navbar-toggle not working on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I made a Wordpress [theme](http://multichallenge.page202.nl) for a customer using Bootstrap 3.2, Roots 7.0.2

But strangely the navbar-toggle doesn't work on my iPhone…
while it does on my desktop.

Searched for solution but nothing works, so I would be very happy if someone is able to help me out. Thanks!

Comment: could you please share some code with us?

Comment: Isn't it easier to look at the code at de accept environment ([link]http://multichallenge.page202.nl[/link]? I'm afraid a code snippet won't work because it works on desktop…